# How do I add JavaScript to a page?

Tags: javascript

I made a module, and I want to add a JavaScript file to that module; I enable the module and obvious it works, but I didn't see the JavaScript file that module should take with.

I just put code similar to the following in `hook_menu()`:

```
function my2form_menu() {
      drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'my2form') . '/abc.js');
}
```

Is it OK?

Comment: this should work, yes - you have several options regarding when to include and in what position etc ..

Comment: When `hook_menu()` implementations are invoked, Drupal is not necessarily outputting a page; that is why the OP doesn't see the JavaScript file added to the page. That apart, the task of `hook_menu()` is not adding JavaScript files to the page, but returning the definition of the menu callbacks the module implements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding a call to `drupal_add_js()` directly in `hook_menu()` doesn't work; the call to `drupal_add_js()` should be added on the code that is executed when Drupal is outputting a page. This means:

- in the implementation of [hook_init()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_init/7)
- in an implementation of [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7), [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7), or [hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter/7)
- in the menu callback for the menu defined from the module

Within a form, Drupal 7 modules can use something similar to the following code, to add a JavaScript file to the currently output page.

```
$form['#attached']['js'] = array(
  drupal_get_path('module', 'my2form') . '/abc.js',
);
```

As alternative, if you write the following line in the [.info file of a module](http://drupal.org/node/542202), the JavaScript file will be added to any page.

```
scripts[] = abc.js
```

The path needs to be relative to the directory containing the module; if the file is contained in a sub-directory of that directory, e.g. javascript, the line should be the following one.

```
scripts[] = javascript/abc.js
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add your js to every page, use [hook_init](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_init/7), if you only need to add it to some existing forms use [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7). It all depends on what your module is doing, so a little more background information will get you a better answer.